# How can I add a node to an existing network?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I created a network with 4 peers using docker-compose and docker for Mac.
I deploy my blockchain on this network successfully.

Now I'm launching a 5th peer using another yml file using the details of one of the previous peer as discovery node.
It appears in the list returned by http://localhost:7050/network/peers however my blockchain is not deployed on this peer and I cannot use it to process transactions.

Do I have to deploy the chaincode again on this peer? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is limitation in Fabric’s versions 0.5 and 0.6 
Network configuration cannot be changed in realtime. In case If you use PBFT consensus, network configuration is hardcoded in:
“fabric/consensus/pbft/config.yaml"

```
# Maximum number of validators/replicas we expect in the network
# Keep the "N" in quotes, or it will be interpreted as "false".
"N": 4
```

The challenge is in updating configuration on all peers synchronously, otherwise they will not be able to reach consensus. 
In one of next Fabric versions this configuration’s parameter will be moved to blockchain and it will be possible to add new peers and modify consensus configuration on the fly.

Update for question in comment: 
Saw only this high level Roadmap proposal:

[image: Proposed Roadmap]

Comment: Thanks clear, is there a tentative roadmap published somewhere?

Comment: Thanks at least it gives some perspective on a v1.0.